# Predictable martingales are constant

Tags: probability-theory

> *Exercise:*  Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a predictable $\mathbb{F}$-martingale. Show that $X_n = X_0$
>   almost surely for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

*Solution:* $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ being predictable means that $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurable so $\mathbf{E}[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_n$ a. s. But using the martingale property we see that $\mathbf{E}[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So we can conclude that $X_n = X_{n-1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and inductively that $X_n = X_0$ a. s. $\square$

---

Is this solution correct? Thank you!

Comment: I would flesh the iterative argument out a bit more if you are required to present it, but yes. Once you have that $X_n = X_{n-1}$ almost surely, then you take $X_{n-1} = \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1} | \mathcal{F}_{n-2}] = X_{n-2}$ almost surely. Specifically you are using the martingale property and measurability property iteratively and alternating.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $(X_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ is a predictable $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ martingale. We have to take advantage of each property :

First, since it is a martingale, we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=X_{n}
\end{equation}

and since it is predictable, we know that $X_{n+1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ measurable, so
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=X_{n+1}
\end{equation}

The above two results yield
\begin{equation}
X_{n}=X_{n+1}
\end{equation}

The proof is an immediate consequence